# Check if file download (method) is completed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, dropbox

This is probably a pretty stupid question, but I haven't been able to find the answer because I don't really know what I'm looking for.

Basically I want to know when the restClient method (which downloads a remote file) is done, because I want to wait for that before I want webView to load the file: `[webView loadRequest:request];`

What would be the best way to do this?

```
[self.restClient loadFile:[NSString stringWithString:filePath] intoPath:[NSString stringWithString:localPath]]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localPath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the delegate on you restClient, probably to the current instance, and perform the loadRequest in the `loadedFile` method:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destPath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is *restClient* (type)? It depends on if the download is done on a background thread (most likely), in which case there should be a delegate callback.

Comment: The download is done on a background thread indeed. How should I implement the delegate callback?

Comment: What is restClient? Do you have access to its implementation code?

Comment: restClient is a class of the Dropbox SDK. I do have access to its implementation code.

Comment: Hmm...it should already have waited until the download is done, but if it isn't, declare a simply delegate, set restClient's delegate to be your current class, and then call the loadRequest method in that delegate callback. But that really should be unnecessary...